# will a Asus Desktop M32BF-US002T Desktop fit a 1060

Tags: windows, desktop, nvidia-geforce

I have a 750ti that is smaller than a 1060 but the new games just are past the graphics card I have in now with the Computer I have held this new one? I have not tried to use the new one because I have not bought it yet and I don't want to waste my money on this if it wont work

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to confirm it yourself but it should fit comfortably with a few changes. Mini ATX is about 9.6 inches on the side, and [your typical 960 is about 9.8](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2862/geforce-gtx-1060-6-gb).

Even with a much longer card, I'm assuming the card will clear the cable management bracket, but there's nothing else I can see that would be an issue
[image]

1060s are *dual slot* cards and you will very likely need to move your wifi antennae lower as the case will allow. In addition unless your power supply has the additional power connectors needed for a more powerful video card, you may need to change your PSU. Check for PCIe power connectors.